# envers and hibernate plugins incompatibility

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I'm using hibernate plugin and trying to integrate envers plugins to my project. But the following issue appears:
when I'm trying to start project it gives me an exception:

```
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] General error during conversion: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/PostInsertEventListener
```

my build config is as follows:

```
{
    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
        compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
        runtime ":envers:2.1.0"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

}
```

I tried to find `PostInsertEventListener` class and I found it but under different package - under `org.hibernate.event.spi` and for some reason it tries to find it in under `org/hibernate/event`. Is it some plugins incompatibility issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `grails dependency-report` to see the conflicts

you can also try replacing the `hib4` plugin with `hib3`. this should most probably be causing the compile error

Comment: I've tried it and it seems that envers doesn't suppot hib4

Comment: so you have the solution